# Hacer Script de Banderas Del Mundo En Registro De Cuenta MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

Hola queridos amigos de stackoverflow, el dia de hoy tengo un problema y es que me gustaria poder hacer un script que cuando los usuarios se registren puedan seleccionar su nacionalidad y bandera de su pais, he buscado por todo el internet y no he podido encontrar un script que me funcione para poder añadirlo a mi web,lo que necesito basicamente es que cuando el usuario se registre le aparezca una opcion que diga  por ejemplo " Country" y que seleccione su pais y luego esos datos meterlos en una base de datos! si alguien esta interesado en ayudarme le estaria muy agradecido, desde ya muchas gracias! o si tienen uno a mano que me puedan dar les estaria infinitamente agradecido, quiero mostrar el script en las estadisticas de mi web, yo se que se necesita de una base de datos y las imagenes de las banderas, muchas gracias y feliz dia! =)

este es el script de registro de nueva cuenta:

```
<?php
include('application/Account.php');

if(!empty($_GET['ref'])){$inviter=$database->filterstringvalue($_GET['ref']);}

?>


<?php include("application/views/html.php");?>
<body class="v35 webkit <?=$database->bodyClass($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']); ?> ar-AE login  perspectiveBuildings <?php echo DIRECTION; ?> season- buildingsV1">
<div id="background">
    
    <div id="bodyWrapper">
        <img style="filter:chroma();" src="img/x.gif" id="msfilter" alt=""/>
        <div id="header">
            <div id="mtop">
                <a id="logo" href="<?php echo HOMEPAGE; ?>" target="_blank" title="<?php echo SERVER_NAME; ?>"></a>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="center">
            <?php include('application/views/menu.php');?>
            <div id="contentOuterContainer" class="size1">
                <div class="contentTitle">&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="contentContainer">
                    <div id="content" class="signup"><h1 class="titleInHeader"><?php echo REG; ?></h1>
                        <?php if($_SESSION['isOkay']){ ?><b style="color:blue;"><?php echo $_SESSION['isOkay']; ?></b><br><br><?php } ?>
                        <?php if($database->config()['regstatus']){ ?>
                        <h4 class="round"><?php echo REGISTER_USERINFO; ?></h4>
                        <form name="snd" method="post" action="anmelden.php">
                            <input type="hidden" name="ft" value="a1" />
                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center">
                                <tbody>
                                <!--<tr class="top">
                                    <th><?php echo INVITED; ?></th>
                                    <td><input class="text" type="text" name="referal"  value="<?php if(!empty($inviter) && is_numeric($inviter)){echo $database->getUserField($inviter,'username',0); }elseif(!empty($inviter) && !is_numeric($inviter)){
                                            echo $inviter;
                                        } ?>" maxlength="15"  />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>-->

                                <th><?php echo NICKNAME; ?></th>
                                <td><input class="text" type="text" name="name" placeholder="<?=anlm0?>" value="<?php echo $form->getValue('name'); ?>" maxlength="15" />
                                    <span class="error"><?php echo $form->getError('name'); ?></span>
                                </td>

                                <tr>
                                    <th><?php echo EMAIL; ?></th>
                                    <td>
                                        <input class="text" type="text"  placeholder="<?=anlm1?>"  name="email" value="<?php echo stripslashes($form->getValue('email')); ?>" />
                                        <span class="error"><?php echo $form->getError('email'); ?></span>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr class="btm">
                                    <th><?php echo PASSWORD; ?></th>
                                    <td>
                                        <input class="text" type="password"  placeholder="<?=anlm2?>" name="pw" value="<?php echo stripslashes($form->getValue('pw')); ?>" maxlength="30" />
                                        <span class="error"><?php echo $form->getError('pw'); ?></span>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                            <br>
                            <h4 class="round"><?php echo REGISTER_MOREINFO; ?></h4>
                            <div class="checks">
                                <input class="check" type="checkbox" id="agb" name="agb" value="1" <?php echo $form->getRadio('agb',1); ?>/>
                                <label for="agb"><?php echo ACCEPT_RULES; ?></label>
                            </div>
                            <br>
                            <div class="btn">
                                <input type="hidden" name="vid" value="0">
                                <input type="hidden" name="kid" value="0">
                                <button type="submit" value="anmelden" name="s1" class="green "  id="btn_signup" title="Register">
                                    <div class="button-container addHoverClick ">
                                        <div class="button-background">
                                            <div class="buttonStart">
                                                <div class="buttonEnd">
                                                    <div class="buttonMiddle"></div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="button-content"><?php echo REG; ?></div>
                                    </div>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                        <?php }else{ ?>
                            Logging is closed in a this server.
                        <?php } ?>
                        <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="contentFooter">&nbsp;</div>
            </div>

        </div>


    </div>
    <div id="ce"></div></div></div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

y este es el codigo de las estadisticas donde quiero que aparezca la nacionalidad del usuario:

```
  <?php
if(!is_numeric($_SESSION['search']) && !empty($_SESSION['search'])) {
    $igrok=OVERVIEW1;
    $nenaiden= STATISTIC3;
    echo "<p class=\"error\">".$igrok." <b>".$_SESSION['search']."</b> ".$nenaiden."</p>";
    $search = 0;
}
else {
$search = $database->FilterVar($_SESSION['search']);
}
include("player_menu.php");
?>

<h4 class="round"><?php echo STATISTIC1; ?></h4>
    <table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" id="player" class="row_table_data">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><?php echo OVERVIEW1; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo OVERVIEW6; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo OVERVIEW8; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo OVERVIEW7; ?></td>
        <?php if($session->access == 9){ ?>
            <td>Controller</td>
        <?php } ?>
        </tr>
        </thead><tbody>
        <?php
        if(isset($_GET['rank'])){
            $multiplier = 1;

        if(is_numeric($_GET['rank'])) {
        if($_GET['rank'] > count($ranking->getRank())) {
        $_GET['rank'] = count($ranking->getRank())-1;
        }
        while($_GET['rank'] > (20*$multiplier)) {
        $multiplier +=1;
        }
        $start = 20*$multiplier-19;
        } else { $start = ($_SESSION['start']+1); }
        } else { $start = ($_SESSION['start']+1); }
        if(count($ranking->getRank()) > 0) {
        $ranking = $ranking->getRank();
        for($i=$start;$i<($start+20);$i++) {
            if(isset($ranking[$i]['username']) && $ranking[$i] != "pad") {

            if($i == $search) {
                echo "<tr class=\"hl\"><td class=\"ra fc\" >";
            }else {
                echo "<tr><td class=\"ra \" >";
            }
                echo $i.".</td><td class=\"pla \" ".($session->access == 9 ? 'style="width:13%"': '').">";
                if($ranking[$i]['access'] > 2){
                    echo"<u><a href=\"spieler.php?uid=".$ranking[$i]['userid']."\">".$database->RemoveXSS($ranking[$i]['username'])."</a></u>";
                } else {
                    echo"<a href=\"spieler.php?uid=".$ranking[$i]['userid']."\">".$database->RemoveXSS($ranking[$i]['username'])."</a>";
                }
                echo"</td><td class=\"al\" >";
                    if($ranking[$i]['aname'] != "") {
                    echo "<a href=\"allianz.php?aid=".$ranking[$i]['alliance']."\">".$database->RemoveXSS($ranking[$i]['aname'])."</a>";
                    }
                    else {
                    echo "-";
                    }
                    echo "</td><td class=\"pop\" >".$ranking[$i]['totalpop']."</td><td class=\"vil\">".$ranking[$i]['totalvillage']."</td>";
                if($session->access == 9){
                    echo '<td>'.$database->getUserInfo($ranking[$i]['userid'])['gold'].'<img src="img/x.gif" title="gold" class="gold">
                    <a href="?getIn='.$ranking[$i]['username'].'">Login</a>
                    </td>';
                }
                    echo '</tr>';
            }
            
        }
        }
        else {
        ?><td class="none" colspan="5"><?php echo STATISTIC2; ?></td>
        <?php }
?>
 </tbody>
</table>
<?php
include("ranksearch.php");
?>
```

yo quiero que el resultado del codigo aparezca despues de
`<td><?php echo OVERVIEW7; ?></td>`
muchas gracias por la infinita ayuda queridos amigos! =)

Comment: Lee [ask] y checa el [tour], tu pregunta es muy amplia y carece de detalles por lo cual terminará cerrada

Comment: ok muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Puedes aplicar la misma lógica que usas para crear un combobox. Las banderas las guardas en la bdd con formato BLOB.

Comment: Hola es que ese el problema, no se programar, por eso hice la pregunta porque no se como hacerlo,he buscado en internet pero solo aparecen plugins y para smf pero no para poder añadirlo en mi web  saludos! =)

Comment: siendo asi, debes comenzar por fundamentos de javascript, html, formulario y luego aprender el lenguaje en el cual trabaja tu backend, luego por ultimo aprender el lenguaje de tu base de datos.

Answer (score 0):

con el siguiente plugin puedes

https://www.jqueryscript.net/form/jQuery-Plugin-For-Country-Selecter-with-Flags-flagstrap.html

```js
$('#demo').flagStrap();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script><link href="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-For-Country-Selecter-with-Flags-flagstrap/dist/css/flags.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-For-Country-Selecter-with-Flags-flagstrap/dist/js/jquery.flagstrap.js"></script>

<div id="demo"
     data-input-name="country"
     data-selected-country="CL"
     data-button-size="btn-md"
     data-scrollable="true"
     data-scrollable-height="250px"
</div>
```

puedes extraer el valor elegido con la funcion

```
$("#demo option[selected]").val()
```

Comment: ok ahora mismo lo pruebo muchas gracias!, pero donde coloco en la pagina de registro de mi web el codigo? es que no se como instalarlo en mi web,y el archivo que me distes se llama demo.php? muchas gracias!

Comment: asumiendo que usas HTML + JS sin framworks, generalmente deberías agregar el <div> dentro de un <form> y el script $('#demo').flagStrap(); que instancia al objeto debería estar dentro de un  $( document ).ready() o equivalente para que se ejecute cuando la pagina ya este cargada y así logre encontrar el <div> que se debe convertir en el combo de paises, luego deberías incluir el valor de este combo en el arreglo u objeto que se envía a tu backend, en tu backend debes hacer que esta nueva variable llegue a la base de datos mediante la modificación de tus controladores y columnas de la DB

Comment: Hola creo que mejor coloco el codigo de mi pagina de registro ok es este:

Comment: debes modificar tu respuesta entonces, o cerrar esta y crear una nueva, explicando el detalle de tu problemática pero primero debes intentarlo por ti mismo y explicar que es lo que te falla.

Comment: ya la modifique querido Jhonnattan Rivera =)

Comment: muy bien, pero te invito a intentar implementar el plugin por ti mismo, y solicitar ayuda cuando encuentres que a pesar de tus intentos no logras hacerlo funcionar. edita, copia, pega, borra, guarda, analiza tu codigo etc.

Comment: ok muchas gracias me gustaria poder hacerlo pero solo necesito una guia y ya aprendiendo lo hare por mi misma cuenta, recuerda que todos los dias se aprende algo nuevo en la vida,, saludos! =)